# why do i have to refresh the page when i delete a row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table-v7

i'm doing the delete row option for my table with data of a api and the delete request works well but i have to refresh the page to update my rows do you know why and what can i do ? i'm using `react-table-v7`

```
const useTableResource = () => {
  const {data} = apiData();
  const resourcesData = data;
  
  const resourcesDataLength = resourcesData.length;
  const query = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 750px)');
 

  const resourcesColumns = useMemo(() => [
    {Header: 'Tittle', accessor: 'name'},
    {
      id: 'delete',
      accessor: () => 'delete',
      disableSortBy: true,
      Cell: ({row}) => <div onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()} style={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}>
        <DeleteModal delb={async () => {
          await axios.delete(`api/resources?_id=${row.original._id}`);
        }}/>

      </div>

    }
  ], []);


  const tableInstance = useTable({
    columns: resourcesColumns,
    data: resourcesData, //here load the data for my table
    disableSortRemove: true,
    initialState: {
      sortBy: [{id: 'resourceType.name', desc: false}],
      pageSize: 10
    }
  }, useSortBy, usePagination);


  return {
    tableInstance,
    resourcesColumns,
    resourcesDataLength
  };
};

export default useTableResource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to refresh the page to update my rows

> It's because, you are **not updating** your **resourceData** based on the operation you do. And react re-renders the component if there is any change made to the state (resourceData).

How can I tell react to re-render the component ?

> One way is to make the apiData() call again after the successful delete operation and update your resourceData state or if you feel, api operation is costly, then alter your resourceData state to remove the deleted element.

Comment: i'm not using useState to manage the data do you if it works with useRowState  ?
[link](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowState)

Comment: @Mark, found this [link](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data) in the documentation that you shared, where it demonstrates the usage of state and update of the table data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options
You can either re-fetch the "resourceData" using your API method after the deletion. Which requires another API call

Or update the delete method to remove the data from the list.

If you want to use the second option I'd recommend using useState to manage the state of the resourceData

Something like

`const {resourceData, setResourceData} = useState(data)`

and in the delete method

`setResourceData(resourceData.filter(record => record.id != id))`

Comment: i dont know why but if i console.log resourceData it show me empty arrays but if i log data console.log show me 5 empty arrays and 3 arrays with objects of data

Comment: i'm not using useState do you if it works with useRowState ?

Comment: [link](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowState)

Answer (score 0):

how i solved this problem,

```
  const [datos, setDatos] = React.useState(React.useMemo(() => data, []));
```

i had to use useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDatos(data);
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).